# Navigation Drawer layout over activity layout

Tags: android

I want to create a navigation drawer that comes on top of the main activity.But with the code here

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>
<RelativeLayout

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".invento">

    <TextView android:text="@string/hello_world" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </RelativeLayout>

<fragment
    android:layout_width="@dimen/nav_drawerWidth"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"
    android:name="com.invento.defcomm.invento16.navigation_drawer"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />
```

I 'am getting the drawer below the action bar, not completely overlapping the entire activity. Please help me out on this and point out what am i doing wrong? Thanks....

Comment: some how i 'am not able to show the full code here.

Comment: Let see here https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

Comment: @Amit thanks. Everything in the above code is working correctly but the navigation drawer comes below the action bar. I would like to know how to correct that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you change your default action bar to a Toolbar. That way you can include the toolbar to your layout and keep the navigation drawer on top of the toolbar as well.

This is the code I use to add a toolbar:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_actionbar"
        style="@style/ToolBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

and then I include the above xml in my layout everywhere.

```
 <include
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    layout="@layout/toolbar_default"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="false"/>
```

So in your xml, you can simply do this:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".invento">

 <include
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    layout="@layout/toolbar_default"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="false"/>

    <TextView android:text="@string/hello_world" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<fragment
    android:layout_width="@dimen/nav_drawerWidth"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"
    android:name="com.invento.defcomm.invento16.navigation_drawer"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And in your Activity, assign the Toolbar as your ActionBar:

```
mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_actionbar);
mToolbar.setLogo(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher)); // Your Logo
mToolbar.setTitle("Title"); // Your Title
setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
```

Comment: Try this link for some extra info on Material Design Action Bars and Navigation Drawers   http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/android-design-support-library-codelab/en

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<!-- The main content view -->
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <!-- Toolbar instead of ActionBar so the drawer can slide on top -->
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:titleTextAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <!-- Real content goes here -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>


<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer" />
```